# convert pdf to text "Can not open file pdf"

Tags: php, pdf, text, text-files

I tried to convert pdf to text with http://www.pdf2text.com/download/P2TServerT.zip
i ran "regsvr32 P2TServer.dll" but this code did'not work

```
<?php
$p2t = new COM("P2TServer.P2T");
$p2t->VerifyLicense("4747457", "345srwr242342423");
$p2t->EngageProcessor(64+32,"5,10,11-15", "");
print $p2t->Convert ("c:\test\test1.pdf", "c:\box\test1.txt");
$p2t = null;
?>
```

The result like this :

Can not open file: c: est est1.pdfDone!

Everyone can help me? please..

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about that particular library, but it looks to me like your paths are not escaped. Try this:

```
<?php
$p2t = new COM("P2TServer.P2T");
$p2t->VerifyLicense("4747457", "345srwr242342423");
$p2t->EngageProcessor(64+32,"5,10,11-15", "");
print $p2t->Convert ("c:\\test\\test1.pdf", "c:\\box\\test1.txt");
$p2t = null;
?>
```